# How can I do this split process with this sequence in R?

Tags: r, sequence

I'm trying to create a corpus with the BILOU format, and I wanted to reuse a table. Where a given sentence is separated by columns, and each column would be an entity. How can I perform a sequence this way, making each string in each row represent the sequence B_xxx, I_xxx, L_xxx. And that it repeats itself from the moment the entity (column) changes.

**Old dataframe:**

```
first_entity <- c("Product and Other","Product2 and Second", "Product")
second_entity <- c("Price and Prices","Price2", "Price3 and example")

df <- data.frame(first_entity, second_entity)
df
----------------------------------------
         first_entity      second_entity
1   Product and Other   Price and Prices
2 Product2 and Second             Price2
3             Product Price3 and example
```

**Desired dataframe:**

```
       Word   Ent
1   Product B_pro
2       and I_pro
3     Other L_pro
4     Price B_pri
5       and I_pri
6    Prices L_pri
7  Product2 B_pro
8       and I_pro
9    Second L_pro
10   Price2 B_pri
11  Product B_pro
12   Price3 B_pri
13      and I_pri
14  example L_pri
```